# Dealing with array while using to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have just started learning ruby on rails and I was using this code to get the json representation of the question model

```
post "api/quizzes/addquestion/#{@quiz.id}",
        { question: 
        { text: "Question Text Example", mark: 2, choices:["a","b","c","d"], right_answer: "a" }    
        }.to_json
```

I got :
choices: [] , empty array 
I don't know the reason for this as all other attributes are sent succesfully. What is the solution for such problem

I am using this while testing the following method:

```
def add_question
            question = Question.new(question_params)
            quiz = Quiz.find(params[:quiz_id])
            if question.save
                quiz.questions << question
                render json: { success: true, data:{:question => question}, info:{} }, status: 201
            else
                render json: { success: false, data:{}, :info => question.errors }, status: 422
            end
        end
def question_params
            params.require(:question).permit(:text, :mark, :choice, :right_answer)
        end
```

the test :

```
class AddingQuestionsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest 
    setup {@quiz = Quiz.create(name: 'Quiz1', subject: 'physics', duration: 10, no_of_MCQ: 5, no_of_rearrangeQ: 5)}
    setup {@question = Question.create(text: "Question Text Example", mark: 2, choices:["a","b","c","d"], right_answer: "a")}   

    test 'successes to add question to a quiz' do       
        post "api/quizzes/addquestion/#{@quiz.id}",
        { question: 
        { text: "Question Text Example", mark: 2, choices:["a","b","c","d"], right_answer: "a" }    
        }.to_json,
        { 'Accept' => Mime::JSON, 'Content-Type' => Mime::JSON.to_s }       
        question_response = json(response.body)
        assert_equal 201, response.status   
        assert_equal @quiz.questions.first, @question
        assert_equal publish_response[:success], true
    end         
end
```

and this is the question model:
    class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
        serialize :choices,Array
        belongs_to :quiz
    end
When I run the test I get failure in:assert_equal @quiz.questions.first, @question
choices: [] 
choices: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

Comment: You don't say where you are getting it as an empty array.  I'm just going to take a guess... :)

If what you have posted is what is showing up in your log but choices is empty when you check your database, is your model configured to allow you to update the choices attribute?

Comment: I have create method and I am testing it I'll update the question with the method ,the test and the model @David Hoelzer

Comment: @DavidHoelzer You can  take a look now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just we need to change

```
def question_params
            params.require(:question).permit(:text, :mark, :choice, :right_answer)
        end
to
def question_params
            params.require(:question).permit(:text, :mark, :right_answer, :choice => [])
        end
```